# How to install matlabengine (Windows 10, MATLAB R2020b, Python 3.8.10)

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-engine

I have the following environment:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.10
- MATLAB R2020b

I'm trying to install `matlabengine` (`pip install matlabengine`) package, and I'm getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: No compatible MATLAB installation found in Windows Registry. This release of MATLAB Engine API for Python is compatible with version 9.13. The found versions were 9.9

1. What am I missing ? (according to https://pypi.org/project/matlabengine/) it seems I'm using the right versions.
2. How can I check the versions I have (9.9 or 9.13 because as I wrote above I have MATLAB R2020b and Python 3.8.10).

Answer (score 7):

The error is about the **MATLAB version**, not the version of `matlabengine` (the Python module).

You wrote that you have MATLAB 2020b. That is the release name for MATLAB version 9.9, as can be seen in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MATLAB&oldid=1110444194#Release_history) on Wikipedia.

As can be read on the description of [matlabengine 9.13.1](https://pypi.org/project/matlabengine/9.13.1/), this engine version requires MATLAB release R2022b (= 9.13).

To use `matlabengine` with MATLAB 2020b, install version [9.9.1](https://pypi.org/project/matlabengine/9.9.1/):

```
python -m pip install matlabengine==9.9.1
```

Comment: You saved me. ChatGPT and Bing Chat cannot answer this. Just installed matlabengine from 2022a with "python -m pip install matlabengine==9.12.0"

Comment: @RoyDai, I'm glad I still cannot be replaced by ChatGPT ;-)

Comment: After few hours of serch & try , the above solution solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the correct version. You can find a [list of the releases on the MathWorks Github](https://github.com/mathworks/matlab-engine-for-python/releases). However, you might still have a challenge picking the supported version for your system which is where I prefer the trial and error method below.

You need to try all versions of MATLAB engine starting from the latest one going backwards. To get a list of all the possible versions, try install one that doesn't exist e.g.

```
$ python -m pip install matlabengine==9.9.2
```

and it will give you an error with the list of possible versions.

What worked for me on Ubuntu was

```
$ python -m pip install matlabengine==9.12.17
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to install specific version of matlabengine.

`pip install matlabengine==9.13.1`

If they cannot find your version, you might need to update pip.

Also, you can check your current matlabengine version.

`pip show matlabengine`

Comment: I have tried to install with (==9.13.1) and got same results.
Maybe it because it wrote the error: "No compatible MATLAB installation found in Windows Regitry." ... ?